# How to apply a gradient to an image in ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I have an image and I want to make it lighter at the top fading to no effect at the bottom. So if the image was a solid green to begin with, at the end it would look like a gradient from light green to green.

I thought I could do something like this (copmositing a white block over the top of the image using a gradient as a mask):

```
convert a.jpg \( +clone -fill white \) \
      \( +clone gradient:white-black  \) \
      -composite out.jpg
```

Or this ('colorize' an image with a gradient that fades to transparent)

```
convert a.jpg \( +clone 'gradient:black-rgba(0,0,0,0)' \) \
        -colorize 50% out.jpg
```

…but neither works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
convert a.jpg \( +clone -fx 'i/w' \) -compose multiply -composite out.jpg
```

This will take a copy of the image and apply the [`-fx` operator](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#fx). The forumla `i/w` goes over every pixel for `i` = 0 to width `w` such that at the left (`i == 0`) the output is zero (black) and at the right (`i == w`) the output is one (white).

Then compose with `multiply` so it fades from pure black on left hand side to the pure original at the rightmost edge.

You can also do things like this:

```
convert a.jpg \( +clone \
  -fx 'i/w < 0.2 ? 0.2 : (i/w -0.2)*4 + 0.2' \
  \) -compose multiply -composite output.jpg
```

Which will darken the left 20% of the image by 80%, then from 40% from the left it has no effect and between 20% and 40% it linearly fades out.

Comment: how would you apply it to a masked region like a circle of radius R, while leaving the rest of the image outside the circle transparent?

Comment: You could do it with maths and ternary operators but it would get very complex. Imagemagick probably has a way to [draw a circle](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#draw). So use that inside the `\( ... \)` bit to create a circle. This case should be a new question really.